# BuildManager.GetCompiledType in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a way in **ASP.NET Core** to get the compiled type of a razor view?

In the "old" ASP.NET MVC this was possible by invoking:

```
var compiledType = System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(fullPath);
```

where `fullPath` is the path to the cshtml razor view.